# Android add shadow to right DrawerLayout

Tags: android

i'm using `DrawerLayout` in my application and i'm trying to set shadow for that, my drawer layout is opening from right and i can not set shadow for that with:

```
drawer_layout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.toolbar_dropshadow, GravityCompat.START);
```

[image]

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, just change `GravityCompat.START` to `GravityCompat.END`.

Comment: @MikeM. yes that right sir. thanks, pleaser reply to my post and let me to accept and upvote that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter in the `DrawerLayout#setDrawerShadow()` method you're using indicates on which drawer you're setting the shadow. In your case, you just need to change `GravityCompat.START` to `GravityCompat.END`.

```
drawer_layout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.toolbar_dropshadow, GravityCompat.END);
```